# How to Embed a Google Doc Chart in Joomla

Tags: joomla2.5, google-docs

How do I embed a Google Docs chart in a Joomla 2.5 custom HTML module?  When I publish a chart and receive the "script" I paste it into a module and then the editor seems to strip the code out.  I have tried 4 different editors and also "no editor" and it still modifies the script.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Google Docs offers an undocumented feature that lets you embed PDF files and PowerPoint presentations in a web page. The files don't have to be uploaded to Google Docs, but they need to be available online.
Here's the code I used to embed the PDF file:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.uom.mx/programas/Kinam%20programa.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

but you should replace the bold URL with your own address. As I mentioned, the document viewer works for PDF and PPT files.